# How to make VS Code editor aware belonging imported packages in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code to write and test python scripts.

Is it possible to make the editor aware of imported modules

to avoid problems listed like

*Module 'numpy' has no 'divmod' member*

Answer (score 1):

You would update the Python interpreter settings according to where modules have been installed. (bottom right of VS Code)

The IDE being used isn't really relevant because you could invoke `/path/to/bin/python`, start a REPL, import the same module, and get the same error

---

Regarding, "numpy has no ... member", based on searching, that is a PyLint issue, not an import issue

[How do I get PyLint to recognize numpy members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553551/how-do-i-get-pylint-to-recognize-numpy-members)

Comment: now I followed the advice in dev.to/ldsands/the-best-linter-for-black-in-vs-code-54a0 . Levi Sands means, it is the best to use the linter flake8 and to add lines in settings – Erhy 13 mins ago

Comment: now, no problems are listed, but I don't know about the ignore arguments e.g. "--ignore=E203"

Comment: flake8args https://stackoverflow.com/a/62317424/2308683

Comment: thank you for the link. I inserted the line-length from the example.